# Simplify SQL Column lookup Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to query the database sys tables to get a list of table, column, and primary key information like this query:

```
select t.name as [TableName]
, (select max(column_id) from sys.columns c where c.object_id = t.object_id) as [ColumnCount]
, (select name from sys.columns c where c.object_id = t.object_id and c.column_id = 1) as [Column01]
, (select name from sys.columns c where c.object_id = t.object_id and c.column_id = 2) as [Column02]
, (select name from sys.columns c where c.object_id = t.object_id and c.column_id = 3) as [Column03]
, (select name from sys.columns c where c.object_id = t.object_id and c.column_id = 4) as [Column04]
, (select name from sys.columns c where c.object_id = t.object_id and c.column_id = 5) as [Column05]
, (select name from sys.columns c where c.object_id = t.object_id and c.column_id = 6) as [Column06]
, (select name from sys.columns c where c.object_id = t.object_id and c.column_id = 7) as [Column07]
, (select name from sys.columns c where c.object_id = t.object_id and c.column_id = 8) as [Column08]
, (select name from sys.columns c where c.object_id = t.object_id and c.column_id = 9) as [Column09]
, (select name from sys.columns c where c.object_id = t.object_id and c.column_id = 10) as [Column10]
, (select name from sys.columns c where c.object_id = t.object_id and c.column_id = 11) as [Column11]
, (select name from sys.columns c where c.object_id = t.object_id and c.column_id = 12) as [Column12]
, (select i.is_primary_key from sys.columns c inner join sys.index_columns ic on ic.column_id = c.column_id and ic.object_id = c.object_id inner join sys.indexes i on ic.index_id = i.index_id and ic.object_id = i.object_id and i.is_primary_key <> 0 where t.object_id = c.object_id and c.column_id = 1) as [Column01PrimaryKey] 
, (select i.is_primary_key from sys.columns c inner join sys.index_columns ic on ic.column_id = c.column_id and ic.object_id = c.object_id inner join sys.indexes i on ic.index_id = i.index_id and ic.object_id = i.object_id and i.is_primary_key <> 0 where t.object_id = c.object_id and c.column_id = 2) as [Column02PrimaryKey] 
, (select i.is_primary_key from sys.columns c inner join sys.index_columns ic on ic.column_id = c.column_id and ic.object_id = c.object_id inner join sys.indexes i on ic.index_id = i.index_id and ic.object_id = i.object_id and i.is_primary_key <> 0 where t.object_id = c.object_id and c.column_id = 3) as [Column03PrimaryKey] 
, (select i.is_primary_key from sys.columns c inner join sys.index_columns ic on ic.column_id = c.column_id and ic.object_id = c.object_id inner join sys.indexes i on ic.index_id = i.index_id and ic.object_id = i.object_id and i.is_primary_key <> 0 where t.object_id = c.object_id and c.column_id = 4) as [Column04PrimaryKey] 
, (select i.is_primary_key from sys.columns c inner join sys.index_columns ic on ic.column_id = c.column_id and ic.object_id = c.object_id inner join sys.indexes i on ic.index_id = i.index_id and ic.object_id = i.object_id and i.is_primary_key <> 0 where t.object_id = c.object_id and c.column_id = 5) as [Column05PrimaryKey] 
, (select i.is_primary_key from sys.columns c inner join sys.index_columns ic on ic.column_id = c.column_id and ic.object_id = c.object_id inner join sys.indexes i on ic.index_id = i.index_id and ic.object_id = i.object_id and i.is_primary_key <> 0 where t.object_id = c.object_id and c.column_id = 6) as [Column06PrimaryKey] 
, (select i.is_primary_key from sys.columns c inner join sys.index_columns ic on ic.column_id = c.column_id and ic.object_id = c.object_id inner join sys.indexes i on ic.index_id = i.index_id and ic.object_id = i.object_id and i.is_primary_key <> 0 where t.object_id = c.object_id and c.column_id = 7) as [Column07PrimaryKey] 
, (select i.is_primary_key from sys.columns c inner join sys.index_columns ic on ic.column_id = c.column_id and ic.object_id = c.object_id inner join sys.indexes i on ic.index_id = i.index_id and ic.object_id = i.object_id and i.is_primary_key <> 0 where t.object_id = c.object_id and c.column_id = 8) as [Column08PrimaryKey] 
, (select i.is_primary_key from sys.columns c inner join sys.index_columns ic on ic.column_id = c.column_id and ic.object_id = c.object_id inner join sys.indexes i on ic.index_id = i.index_id and ic.object_id = i.object_id and i.is_primary_key <> 0 where t.object_id = c.object_id and c.column_id = 9) as [Column09PrimaryKey] 
, (select i.is_primary_key from sys.columns c inner join sys.index_columns ic on ic.column_id = c.column_id and ic.object_id = c.object_id inner join sys.indexes i on ic.index_id = i.index_id and ic.object_id = i.object_id and i.is_primary_key <> 0 where t.object_id = c.object_id and c.column_id = 10) as [Column10PrimaryKey] 
, (select i.is_primary_key from sys.columns c inner join sys.index_columns ic on ic.column_id = c.column_id and ic.object_id = c.object_id inner join sys.indexes i on ic.index_id = i.index_id and ic.object_id = i.object_id and i.is_primary_key <> 0 where t.object_id = c.object_id and c.column_id = 11) as [Column11PrimaryKey] 
, (select i.is_primary_key from sys.columns c inner join sys.index_columns ic on ic.column_id = c.column_id and ic.object_id = c.object_id inner join sys.indexes i on ic.index_id = i.index_id and ic.object_id = i.object_id and i.is_primary_key <> 0 where t.object_id = c.object_id and c.column_id = 12) as [Column12PrimaryKey] 
from sys.tables t 
;
```

Is there a way to simplify the query instead of continuing to add more columns manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this - does that give you what you're looking for?

```
SELECT
    ColumnName = c.Name,
    SchemaName = s.Name, 
    TableName = t.Name,
    i.Name, i.is_primary_key
FROM
    sys.columns c 
INNER JOIN 
    sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.indexes i ON i.object_id = t.object_id
```

It should give you the column name, the schema and table name, the index name and whether or not that index is a primary key

Comment: It does in a sense, but I was wondering if there was a way to get the SQL in the same kind of format where it lists table name, and then all the columns. I'm thinking I'm going to use what you gave me and apply a PIVOT to it somehow.